# Laravel MongoDB: relationship using ID in json object

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have a User and Post model in [MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb#relationships) and want to create relationship: $user->posts()

Post does not contain field `user_id` but instead contains object `author` that contains `user_id` field.

E.g.

```
$post = [
  'title' => "Hello",
  'author' => [
    'user_id' => 123,
    'alias' => 'John',
  ]
];
```

How can I refer to the id `author.user_id`?

I tried:

```
# User.php

public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'id', 'author.user_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you try `return $this->embedsMany(Post::class, 'author.user_id')` in your `post()` method?

Comment: `embedsMany` is the same as `hasMany` but embeds the relationship in the parent object.  Checked: does not give the wanted result. In addition: it returns a Post collection, but actually contains the User.